# Struts2 interceptor - how to read action parameters

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, struts2

I have an ID request parameter in my action class, when it is intercepted how can the interceptor read this ID parameter for checking in order to authenticate a user.

Comment: Normally the action would set a value in the session. For that use SessionAware. The interceptor only checks the value in the session. The log out action is equally straight forward (removes value from session).

Comment: Don't do the authentication itself in an interceptor.

Comment: @DaveNewton I would like to know why it's not best practice authenticating the user in interceptor. Please don't consider it out of topic.

Comment: @DaveNewton users are authenticated using a JNDIRealm linked to LDAP, but I need to check users against a database field (based on an itemID) to see if they have permission to edit the item. They either exist in the database record as a permitted editor or are a member of a AD superuser role group. Let me know your thoughts on this.

Comment: @MohanaRaoSV Interceptors are intended to provide functionality across broad portions of an application. The act of authentication itself is very narrow in scope and belongs in an action or as part of a third-party solution. Checking for the *results* of authentication *is* reasonable in an interceptor.

Comment: @user1277546 That's [authorization, not authentication](http://people.duke.edu/~rob/kerberos/authvauth.html). How I personally would do it would depend on a variety of factors. If it's a "unified" edit action I'd probably still do it in the action since it's not an app-wide cross-cutting concern.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ActionContext` for getting parameters map:

```
Map<String, Object> parameters = ActionContext.getContext().getParameters();
```